How can I establish attribution control on click event with Leaflet?
I have a Leaflet map with 2 layers. I would like to be able to trigger an action on $('.attributionLink').click(), but the click only  registers when layer1 (default) is active. After changing active layer, and even after going back to layer1, the event no longer registers.
I tried creating 2 anchor elements with separate ids and 2 separate event handlers, but no effect.
I also tried adding my own attribution control, but because it pulls the 'attribution' option from layers, I end up with double attribution control.
var layer1 = L.tileLayer(urlTemplate1, {
    maxZoom: 20,
    attribution: '<a href='#' class='attributionLink'>Attribution</a>'

var layer2 = L.tileLayer(urlTemplate2, {
    maxZoom: 20,
    attribution: '<a href='#' class='attributionLink'>Attribution</a>'
});


Please show us the code that does not work? You just shown the tile setup... How do you set up the click handler? Do you trigger the click event or add a handler?

I just use .click() method inside of $(document).ready( () => {} ) :
$('.attributionLink').click( () => {   console.log('clicked');    });

So you set the event on document ready, then when you change layer the attribution link is removed and a new one placed at its place. This means the event is not on the new element. You could use event delegation: $(leafletContainer).on('click','.attributionLink',()=>{console.log('clicked'});

Thanks @Salketer, but I tried that too - no effect. Something happens when changing the layers. Perhaps I should somehow add the handler when the layer gets changed.

Sorry, didn't read your answer properly. This is my forst post on SE! It works, I added it on $('.leaflet-control'). Thanks a lot!

We'll only be able to provide useful help when you show us the code you tried, to create a minimal reproduction.

Salketer's suggestion worked:
$('.leaflet-control').on('click', '.attributionLink', () => { 

    console.log('clicked');
    
});

